# How to rightly edit nd array in python (using vector space )?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a n dimensional array in python = X.

It has float values. I want to replace all values in X> .35 with 0 and all values <= .35 with 1.

If i try ,

```
X[X>.35]=0 ;
X[X<=.35]=1
```

or vice versa , all my array is changing to 0 or 1 (clearly as one statment is execute after other )

Answer (score 1):

in short:

```
Y = X <= .35 # will be boolean
Y = Y.astype(float) # convert to float if you like
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply cast a boolean array to numbers. False will become 0 and True will become 1.

```
X = (X <= 0.35).astype(numpy.int32)
```

Comment: thanks for replying , But finally I want a nd array which has both 0 and 1. In this case i am getting all 0 in my nd array

Comment: @A.wadhawan: You just call this statement, there is no need to run both `X[X>.35]=0;X[X<=.35]=1` anymore.